# How do you scale both sides in axis Z while the other side is less affected?

Tags: coordinates

As you can see in the link below, I have a horizontal row of rectangles standing up and need the ones on the left side to shrink in height ONLY like a volume level. I am kinda stuck here...

[image]
http://advancessss.deviantart.com/art/Help-627857402?ga_submit_new=10%253A1471051916

Comment: As I say in my question, scaling in Z axis doesn't cut it, I need only the left side to scale in Z, and, only in hight, to be like a volume bar ex. ,il

Comment: What I see are two halves of a sphere which are separated. The left half ringed with stripes which I presume are the rectangles you either want to scale smaller in the Z, or reduce their height on the sphere's surface, is this right?

Comment: Ok so yes those little rectangles are the guys, but, as you can see, I need their height to lower as they go the left direction, and if I scale them in Z then they all do, I want the rightwards ones to be *less affected, while only height is scaled. Lol obviously my objective is clear now, so if there's another way then that's also fine.

Comment: You can use proportional editing with a linear falloff : hide all the faces you don't want to move, keeping only the little rectangles visible. Then select the one the most on the left, scale Z and tune the proportional editing size.

Comment: I found it, but 2 problems remain, the stretched "volume bar of rectangles" stretched perfectly vertical, but all of the rectangles sit in air on a angle you see, 2cdly the bottom stretched and looks like a pyramid, need volume barrr.

Comment: Kinda-of fixed problem 1, selecting the last rectangle's bottom face only scales Z in hieght moosstly, bottom still kind-of enlargens downward.

Comment: Well, it'll work, I scaled the top of the left side by selecting left side's lower face, then after scale the left become more flat since the rectangle wasn't sitting in perfect horizontalness in the air, then I'm putting a face up really high, then low, repeat, to move left side G axis leaving lower feet of rectangles half in wall hence switching to really up high/low repeat (to affect the scale beacon point).

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to creating this effect with a mesh, you could use an array with a custom object offset, like in this blend here:

[image]

All you need is a Plane (Or Cube) plus an empty. The empty should be created at the origin of the Cube to easily understand how the effect works. Then, add an array modifier to the cube.

[image: array]

Instead of using the Relative Offset, which is the default, you can use the object offset and choose the Empty. Now, each element of the array receives the Transform differences between the cube and the empty. Move the empty to the side a bit, and you'll see what it means. If you now scale the empty only in the Z direction, you get the effect which (I think) you want. Each array element is a scaled down version of the element before. So the first one has Z = 0.9, the second one Z = 0.9 * 0.9, and so on.

To put it on a circle, use 'Simple Deform' or curve modifiers, whatever works best for you.

Comment: Can you do it for me? I'm thinking I may try to rotate them all to the center of the giant sphere else z scale would look like a coat hanger, and then selecting all top faces, then one by one scale Z 2 arrows keys, deselect one by one, repeat.

Comment: What sucks is that each rectangle isn't just made of 4 faces.