# How do you proportionally scale multiple objects instead of meshes?

Tags: coordinates

So that the effect you get is a row of rectangles increasing in height while each top face is not on a angle but rather perfectly horizontal. (scaling all mesh in one "object" makes the top face rise linear like a rectangle with a top face on a slope)

Comment: I hope they don't flag this as "too broad" or "unclear" ... I get it, but don't know the answer, but am hoping you do get the answer as I need to do something similar. (I'll post of course, if I figure it out :)) ... A parametric version (via python?) would be useful, so that we could control height, span, separation, etc.  It might also be good to understand why the answer to your other question doesn't also answer this one. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/how-do-you-scale-both-sides-in-axis-z-while-the-other-side-is-less-affected